# Is this a valid proof that $\forall x,y≥0, x≥y \Longrightarrow x^2 ≥y^2$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Sorry if this is a basic question but I just want to verify; my textbook does not take this approach.

Theorem: $\forall x,y≥0, x≥y \Longrightarrow x^2 ≥y^2$.

Proof: $x≥y \Longrightarrow \exists c \in \mathbb{R_{≥0}}$ $\text{s.t. }$ $y+c = x$

so $x^2 = (y+c)^2 = y^2 + 2yc + c^2 ≥ y^2$ since $2yc + c^2≥0$ because no number is negative with equality iff $c=0$, or $x=y$.

Comment: It entirely depends on what axioms and theorems you've already set up. Context is important here.

Comment: Your proof seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively

multiplying by $y$ gives $x\ge y\implies xy\ge y^2$

and by $x$ gives $x\ge y\implies x^2\ge xy$

thus $x^2\ge y^2$

Comment: The question is: "Is my proof correct?".

Comment: It is correct but, as someone said, the better question is which "facts" you are allowed to use in your proof. For this proof, you need to know that you can multiply both sides of an inequality by a positive number. For yours, you need to know that $x\ge y\implies x=y+c$ for some $c$. For example.